# nextjs won't build on server

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When I ran `npm run build` for nextjs it does build in windows but it won't build on linux server. The problem is that build process cant resolve relative paths of my components.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Layout from "components/Layout";
import WithAuth from "components/WithAuth";
import Head from "next/head";

class Profile extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Head>
          <title>TripeMa</title>
          <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
          />
          <link
            rel="shortcut icon"
            type="image/x-icon"
            href="/static/images/tripe-ma-app-icon-rec.ico"
          />
          <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
          <meta name="theme-color" content="#d0f4f0" />
        </Head>
        <Layout Component={WithAuth} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default connect()(Profile);
```

> > 1.0.0 build /home/user/site
> >     next build
>
> Using external babel configuration
>   Location: "/home/user/site/.babelrc.js"
>   Failed to build
>   { Error: (client) ./pages/profile.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../components/WithAuth' in '/home/useri/site/pages'
>    @ ./pages/profile.js 20:0-46

Comment: _"it won't build on linux server"_ and what specific error message(s) does it fail with?

Comment: Do you have a webpack setup that adds `components` to webpack's `resolve.modules` so that you magically point to `components` as a root level import? if not you need to always use relative paths for importing files not in node_modules

Comment: @underscore_d can not resolve WithAuth module in profile.js this my profile.js file

Comment: @AndyRay yes i'm using .babelrc with module-resolver plugin

Comment: It's suspicious there are platform specific errors, that isn't usually the case with node. Are you running the same command on both platforms? Can you add the full error output?